# ANOVA repeated measure on multiple data frames r

Tags: r, for-loop, anova

I have hundreds of data frames. I need to perform ANOVA RM tests on each of these data frames. The output should be one single data frame with the mean of each p-value.

I tried:

```
#crate dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(16,sample(-10:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(16,sample(-10:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
df3 <- data.frame(replicate(16,sample(-10:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
Group <- c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8))
Time <- c(rep("before",4),rep("after",4),rep("before",4),rep("after",4))
Name <- rep(rep(1:4, 4))
conds <- data.frame(Name,Time,Group)
#create list
list <- list(df1,df2,df3)

#for loop ANOVA repeated measures
for ( i in list){
  data <- cbind(conds,i)
  t=NULL
  name <- colnames(data)[4:ncol(data)]
  for(i in 4:ncol(data)) { z <- aov(data[,i] ~ Group*Time+Error(Name/(Group*Time)), data=data) 
  sz <- as.list(summary(z))
  t <- as.data.frame(c(t,sz[4]$`Error: Name:Group:Time`[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1]))
  t
  }
}
mean(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R as a vectorized language is designed to avoid `for` loops where possible. You could do an `sapply` approach.

When you list your data frames use names like `df1=`, which later helps in the `res`ult on which of them were done calculations.

<sup>(And don't use `list` as object name since you'll get confused because there is also a `list` function. Also `data`, `df` and friends are "bad" names, you may always check, using e.g. `?list` if the name is already occupied.)</sup>

```
list1 <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)

res <- sapply(list1, function(x) {
  dat <- cbind(conds, x)
  sapply(dat[-(1:3)], function(y) {
    z <- aov(y ~ Group*Time + Error(Name/(Group*Time)), data=dat)
    sz <- summary(z)
    p <- sz$`Error: Name:Group:Time`[[1]][1, 5]
    p
  })
})
```

From the resulting matrix we take the column means.

```
colMeans(res)
#       df1       df2       df3 
# 0.4487419 0.4806528 0.4847789
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(16,sample(-10:10,16,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(16,sample(-10:10,16,rep=TRUE)))
df3 <- data.frame(replicate(16,sample(-10:10,16,rep=TRUE)))
conds <- data.frame(Name=c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8)), 
                    Time=c(rep("before",4),rep("after",4),
                           rep("before",4),rep("after",4)),
                    Group=rep(1:4, 4))
```

Comment: just curious: I got the same error message with your code and also the code from @Giffredo: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 16, 10` because the row length of `conds` and  the `df`s in list are not the same. Do you not get this error message?

Comment: @DominikS.Meier Yeah sorry, we had a small thunderstorm here in Switzerland, and I wanted to add the data I've used. Indeed, `cond` and `df*` need to be equal in row numbers. See updated answer.

Comment: Ah ok. No worries, we have similar weather at the moment here in Basel.

Comment: @jay.sf thank you very much for your suggestion about R and the script you create!